# Register and unregister a handler while iterating throught the vector of handlers

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have got a very small program which starts a thread and dispatches events to the registered set of handlers. Handlers class look as follows.

```
class Handler
{
public:
    /* OnEvent must return void. This is part of the user interface agreement */
    virtual void OnEvent(struct Event*) = 0;
    virtual ~Handler();
};
```

Handlers are kept inside the vector

```
std::vector<Handler*> handlers;
```

I can add a handler to the vector using register function
and delete a handler from the vector using unregister function. Handlers can
either be added or removed within the OnEvent function.

Prototypes are below

```
void registerHandler(Handler *h);
void unregisterHandler(Handler *h);
```

Thread function looks as follows. It will block on event and once event is received it will dispatch this event to every handler which is in the vector

```
void thread_function()
{
    struct Event* e = getEvent();


    /* Function will receive an event and will invoke handlers one by one */
    for(auto s = 0; s < handlers.size(); ++s)
    {
        /* Register and unregister function can be called inside OnEvent. */
        handlers[s]->OnEvent();
    }
}
```

What would be the most optimal way to add and remove a handler from the vector inside OnEvent function?

My idea was.
When register is called inside OnEvent I will push back a handler to the handlers list.
But I cant think of any way how to remove handler from the vector.
If I remove a handler from the vector the iterators will not be valid anymore.
Will be very interesting to hear your thoughts, guys.

Thank you

Comment: if you care more about the validity of the iterators, maybe use `std::list`

Comment: This is missing an import piece of the spec: What is supposed to happen when handlers are added or removed in OnEvent? Should newly added handlers get the currently processing event? Should removed and not-yet processed handlers still get the currently processing event? I would personally answer no to the first and yes to the second question and then you can just copy the list before iteration. But I don't know your use-case.

Comment: This is a really great detail, Chronial. I havent thought about it. Newly added handlers will not get a currently processed event I suppose. Removed handlers and not-yet processed should not get the currently processing event. Could you please explain how do you want to use a copy in that case? I was thinking of wrapping a handler in a different class which will have a couple of extra flags and use a vector of the wrappers rather than the handlers. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with handler changes only taking effect after event processing, you can just copy the handler array:

```cpp
std::vector<Handler*> handlers;

void thread_function(){
  struct Event* e = getEvent();
  std::vector<Handler*> handlersCopy = handlers;
  for(Handler* h : handlersCopy) {
    h->OnEvent();
  }
}
```

If you want to prevent processing of handlers that are removed during processing, you could do something like this:

```cpp
std::vector<Handler*> handlers;
bool isDispatching = false;
std::unordered_set<Handler*> disabledHandlers;

void unregisterHandler(Handler *h){
  handlers.erase(handlers.find(h));
  if (isDispatching){
     disabledHandlers.insert(h);
  }
}

void thread_function(){
  struct Event* e = getEvent();
  isDispatching = true;
  std::vector<Handler*> handlersCopy = handlers;
  for(Handler* h : handlersCopy) {
    if(disabledHandlers.find(h) != disabledHandlers.end()){
      continue;
    }
    h->OnEvent();
  }
  isDispatching = false;
  disabledHandlers.clear();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I think this a very good approach to this particular problem. The only thing which I dont like too much is the copy of the handlers. We can create a copy which may contain thousands of items and it will be on the stack. I think it would be better to use make_unique with handlers as a const reference and construct handlersCopy on the heap. What do you think?

Comment: What do you think of having a flag for each handler. Flag will be set if a handler is removed while isDispatching is set to true. After a dispatch we will go through the vector of handlers and identify the ones which have to be removed. The only problem extra data member is not allowed for Handler.

Comment: The copy of the handlers is not an issue. They will not be copied to the stack – `std::vector` holds its data on the heap. It also fast. It's one memcpy – way faster than the thousands of function pointer calls about to happen. The flag solution sounds more complicated and I don't see the advantage.